# Not able to recognize audio in Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been building a voice assistant in Python. I have Python 3.9 installed in Windows 10. I have checked that my microphone is working in other cases, but not in this case. I have tried a lot with `energy_threshold` but nothing works. I have installed the latest PyAudio version. Can someone please help?
The following code runs till recognizing and then returns *Unable to recognize your voice* that is, it jumps to **exception code**.

```
import pyaudio
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import wikipedia
import webbrowser
import os
import smtplib
import random

engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[0].id)


def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()


def takeCommand():
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:

    print("Listening...")
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    audio = r.listen(source)

try:
    print("Recognizing...")
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
    print(f"User said: {query}\n")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Unable to Recognize your voice.")
    return "None"

return query


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()

        if "wikipedia" in query:
            speak("Searching Wikipedia...")
            query = query.replace("wikipedia", "")
            results = wikipedia.summary(query, sentences=3)
            speak("According to Wikipedia")
            print(results)
            speak(results)

        elif "open youtube" in query:
            speak("Here you go to Youtube\n")
            webbrowser.open("youtube.com")

        elif "open google" in query:
            speak("Here you go to Google\n")
            webbrowser.open("google.com")

        elif "open stackoverflow" in query:
            speak("Here you go to Stack Overflow. Happy Programming!\n")
            webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")
```